# how to change the backgroundcolor in mailcomposer application in iphone

Tags: iphone

How to change the  views backgroundcolor in mailcomposer application in iphone?

I already used `mail.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];` but it's not giving any result.

If any one know the answer please  tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, unfortunately.

The controls on top of the view will hide the color change.